# What does it mean when a .nuget package has no elements in a dependency group? What version of Microsoft.Charp do I need?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package, csvhelper

I'm trying to understand the dependency tree of the [CSVHelper nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/)

Under dependencies it indicates it's dependencies by Framework. We're using .NETFramework4.5. Each of the dependencies is a nuget package reference and thus my understanding is the version indicated in the "Microsoft.Csharp (>= 4.5.0)" is saying that it depends on the nuget *package versioned 4.5* which technically does not mean that the assembly itself (Microsoft.CSharp.dll" is v4.5.0.

Going to the link for Microsoft.CSharp and downloading the nuget package, the .net45 folders have no content. How do I know what version of the Microsoft.CSharp assembly CSVHelper is using?

From what I can tell, .net framework 4.5 installs v4.0.3.30319 of Microsoft.CSharp and not v4.5 like one might imagine. So its unclear to me whether the Microsoft.Csharp assembly installed with .net framework 4.5 is sufficient for use with CSVHelper. If not, we'd have to include the necessary assembly as part of our installation package; however, again there is no indication what version to use only a nuget package version with empty .net framework folders. There are folders for .net standard that I suppose could be used as long as we follow the [.net framework .net standard compatibility chart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard)

Any insight would be appreciated.

Anyo

Comment: You are putting way too much effort into that. Just install the nuget package and nuget will take care of the dependencies.

Comment: And the language and the framework have different versioning strategies anyway.  In .NET Framework-land, the top version is 4.8.  In .NET Core-land, it's 3.1.  C# version 8.0 was recently released

Comment: In most cases the dependency elements are auto generated by the .NET Core SDK tooling, so the meaning of versions doesn't matter much. But if you really want to learn `Microsoft.CSharp`, its manifest is empty, https://www.fuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CSharp/4.5.0 , which shows its goal is to define relationship with other packages, such as `System.Reflection.TypeExtensions`. Compared 4.5 with 4.7 and you can observe the changes the author tried to implement. The actual assembly never changes and is always part of the underlying runtime, so this package is empty.

Comment: @LegacyCode That is true locally but when making an installer I need to know what version to include in the MSI. That is where my confusion lies. .NET 4.5 installs v4.0.3 of Microsoft.Csharp but the the Microsoft.Csharp that nuget pulls from nuget.org is from the v4.5 nuget package. And that package doesn't make clear what version its using.